# How to attach an image file to a randomly rolled number that will display in a JPanel

Tags: java, inheritance, random, jframe, jpanel

I need to create a program that will randomly roll 5 dice and then display the faces of these dice in a JPanel, just like a Yahtzee game. I have images of each die face and am having trouble trying to attach my randomly rolled number to an image. So for instance if the random number is 1 then it will display the die face 1 for five different faces. What I have below is my Die class, Panel class and my GameDrive in that order. Sorry for all the codes copied over and not sure if the driver is needed to solve this problem but dint know where the code needed to be written to work.

```
public class Die implements Comparator {
    private int face;
    public Die() {
        super();
        face = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    }
    public Die(int f){
        super();
        face = f;
    }
    public int getFace() {
        return face;
    }
    public void setFace(int face) {
        this.face = face;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Die [face=" + face + "]";
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this.getFace() == ((Die)obj).getFace());
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(Object a, Object b) {
        Die d1 = (Die)a;
        Die d2 = (Die)b;

        if (d1.getFace() == d2.getFace())
            return 0;
        if (d1.getFace() > d2.getFace())
            return 1;

        return -1;
    }
}
```

panel class

```
public class Panel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage [] img = new BufferedImage [6];
    private int w = 0, h = 0, xloc = 0, yloc = 0;

    public Panel() {
        super();
        try {
            img[0] = ImageIO.read(new File("Die1.jpg"));
            img[1] = ImageIO.read(new File("Die2.jpg"));    
            img[2] = ImageIO.read(new File("Die3.jpg"));    
            img[3] = ImageIO.read(new File("Die4.jpg"));    
            img[4] = ImageIO.read(new File("Die5.jpg"));
            img[5] = ImageIO.read(new File("Die6.jpg"));    
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1300, 600)); 
        w = img[0].getWidth();
        h = img[0].getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        xloc = 0;
        yloc = 0;
        for (BufferedImage i : img)
        {
            g.drawImage(i, xloc, yloc, w, h, null);
            xloc += w;
        }

        yloc += h;
        xloc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < img.length; i++)
        {
            g.drawImage(img[i], xloc, yloc, w, h, null);
            xloc += w;
        }
    }
}
```

driver

```
public class GameDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame f = new Frame();
        ArrayList<Die> roll = new ArrayList<Die>(5);

        for (int i =0; i < 5; i++)
            roll.add(new Die());

        roll.sort(roll.get(0));

        for (Die e : roll)
            System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me just from skimming over your code that your biggest problem is figuring out where the dice should be displayed. I would suggest that often the quickest way to make progress on this is to start by drawing filled rectangles on your JPanel where you'd like the images to be. Once you've done that you should be a lot closer.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your Panel, you need to pass it a reference to the dice to display.

(I think this is what you are asking)

You could pass in some Die values in the constructor and then reference them in you "paint" method, for example...

```
public class Panel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage [] img = new BufferedImage [6];
    private int w = 0, h = 0, xloc = 0, yloc = 0;
    private Die[] state;

    public Panel(Die[] state) {
        super();
        this.state = state;
        try {
            img[0] = ...
            ...
            img[5] = ImageIO.read(new File("Die6.jpg"));    
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1300, 600)); 
        w = img[0].getWidth();
        h = img[0].getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // ...I got rid of the bit that just draws all of the faces...

        xloc = 0;
        yloc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i++)
        {
            int imageIndex = state[i].getFace() - 1;
            g.drawImage(img[imageIndex], xloc, yloc, w, h, null);
            xloc += w;
        }
    }
```

}

(I have not tried to run this obviously, so it might not compile!)

It does not look like you are creating this Panel in any of the code you posted, but assuming you want to display it in your main method, you'd need to do something like this...

```
public class GameDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame f = new Frame();
        ArrayList<Die> roll = new ArrayList<Die>(5);

        for (int i =0; i < 5; i++)
            roll.add(new Die());

        // This is a bit strange...
        roll.sort(roll.get(0));

        for (Die e : roll)
            System.out.println(e);

        // Create the panel
        Panel panel = new Panel(roll.toArray(new Die[0]));

        // TODO put it in a frame and show it
    }

}
```

Comment: So I can get the die images to display on their own just fine but I need to make a switch or if-else loop (I think it needs a loop, not sure)  that will assign the picture to the random number that is rolled. the rolls in my main where just there to make sure my dice is working right and the roll.sort just sorts them from lowest to greatest before displaying them. My frame look like this that has my panel in it.

Comment: public class Frame extends JFrame {
 
 private Panel p = null;
 
 public Frame() {
  super();
  p = new Panel();
  this.getContentPane().add(p);
  this.pack();
  this.setVisible(true);
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 }

}